# retreive a specific fields in realtime database with firebase

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently learning Firebase. I have this path 'users/uid/key,' and my question is, how can I retrieve all the fields of 'firstname' so that I can use them with RecyclerView?

```
{
"6lcSTbUuivXBUJbdwcjYcbc3d8j1": {
"-NXvxRMb8UEJEwGcLx96": {
"age": "23",
"firstname": "jack",
"lastname": "nick"
},
"-NXvx_DsNPIoJKDgbdiX": {
"age": "55",
"firstname": "john",
"lastname": "tristian"
}

      },
      "DEvUIPnT15NowmrawbHZmjDHQBw1": {
        "-NY-7qtEqPQWqxdmKTBO": {
          "age": "18",
          "firstname": "andrew",
          "lastname": "cena"
        }
      }
    }
```

Here is my code:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child("firstname").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", task.getException());
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("firebase", String.valueOf(task.getResult().getValue()));
                }
            }
        });
```

here is the result in Log it return me null

```
2023-07-08 22:06:57.961  9508-9508  firebase com.example.firebaserecyclerview   D  null
```

Someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here the code :

```
mDatabase.child("users").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<>();

        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for (DataSnapshot keySnapshot : userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                DataSnapshot firstNameSnapshot = keySnapshot.child("firstname");
                String firstName = firstNameSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                if (firstName != null) {
                    firstNames.add(firstName);
                }
            }
        }

        // Use the 'firstNames' list with your RecyclerView adapter here

        Log.d("firebase", "First names: " + firstNames);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

if you want to get 'firstname' fields of the current user just add the method `.child("uid")` Here is an example:

```
mDatabase.child("users").child("uid").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> firstNames = new ArrayList<>();

        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            DataSnapshot firstNameSnapshot = userSnapshot.child("firstname");
            String firstName = firstNameSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            if (firstName != null) {
                firstNames.add(firstName);
            }
        }

        // Use the 'firstNames' list with your RecyclerView adapter here

        Log.d("firebase", "First names: " + firstNames);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```